# How to fix GPG error on Intel Linux Graphics Installer?

Tags: apt, intel-graphics, ppa

I'm trying to use Intel Graphics Installer, but i get the following error:

```
E:GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

I've searched through the internet, but none of the answers i found helped me to solve this issue.

Also, using the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get a similar error at the end, sometimes accusing different ppa's.
What should i do?

Comment: I'd blame a spotty internet connection. Are you behind a proxy, firewall, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this at one point or another.

This is generally a network issue.

Are you:

- Behind/Forced to use a proxy?
- Have a spotty internet connection?
- Etc...

You should check your network. If that doesn't solve your issue(s), you may need to contact your ISP.